# Difference between numpy.argsort and torch.argsort

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have checked argsort function of pytorch and numpy are same by definition.

However, when I use those functions along different size of random tensor(or ndarray), It makes difference. I have no idea why this difference is observed.

Example code:

[image]

and results below,

[image]

Comment: `argsort` by default is not stable, both `numpy` and `torch`. You might have differences even between two runs using the same library.

Comment: That said, it seems like floating point precision is also a factor. Passing `dtype=torch.float64` to `torch.rand` removes the misaligned indices.

Comment: Hi! it is a good quesion, but could you please replace the image with your code with the properly formatted text code? It is easier for other people to copy and play with and it's more scalable than image :)

Comment: @Proko Good Idea :)  I edit my post properly now.

Comment: @QuangHoang When I start from type of float64, there is no diff between torch and numpy like you say. However, the other cases(float32 or float64 cast from float32) make still difference.

Answer (score 0):

> ... in general, the actual implementation will vary with data type.

From the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html). Since PyTorch tensors are 32bit float precision by default, and numpy arrays 64 bit, the behaviour is not guaranteed to be consistent.

Comment: In my experience, I observed some error indices using torch.argsort in large size of float32 tensor. Anyway can I understand that both functions are 'inaccurate'?